# Accessing an old HDD via USB

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb

I found my old computer the other day, and realized that I haven't turned it on in years. I wanted to turn it on to see what I could find on it, but realized that the power supply etc. is malfunctioning.

Now I want to access the old HDD from it, but I don't want to plug it directly into my computer and motherboard.

**Can I, with some gadget or cable, access this old HDD via an USB port?**

Comment: When my old laptop died, a technical support person placed it's HDD in such a gadget which had a USB output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to plug it directly to your motherboard, you will need to buy a SATA to USB adapter (or IDE to USB, depends on the HDD's interface).

Regarding the power supply, these adapters come with it built in, like [this one](http://dx.com/p/889u3-usb-3-0-to-sata-ide-cable-set-57576) (just a quick product example, I'm not suggesting this adapter in particular).
As you can see, there's a USB cable and a power plug which connects to the adapter itself.